# Does the 100+ GB blockchain database contain every transaction?

Tags: blockchain, algorithms, whitepaper

Does the 100+ GB blockchain database contain every transaction since the beginning, or only a digest of them?

I've read Nakamoto's paper and I see:

> the spent transactions before it can be discarded to save disk space [...] Merkle Tree  [...]

thus this question: is the 100+ GB blockchain already the result of a space-saving lossy process?

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain contains every **confirmed** transaction since the beginning. There are some tricks to save disk space of course.

Comment: What is discarded in the blockchain then, according to Nakamoto's paper?

Comment: In Bitcoin Core's database, there are no tricks to save disk space assuming you run a non-pruning node.

Comment: I mean pruning, but I do not want to mention complicated things in simple answer to a simple question